# Select options or drop-down menu in a column in v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I wanted to create a **drop-down** menu options in **v-data-table**

```
<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="res"
      :options.sync="options"
      :server-items-length="totalRes"
      :loading="loading"
      loading-text="Loading ..... Please wait"
      :footer-props="{
        itemsPerPageOptions: [5, 10, 20, 40],
        itemsPerPageText: 'Res per page',
      }"
      class="elevation-23"
    >
    </v-data-table>

data () {
    return {
        res: [],
        totalRes: 0,
        search: '',
        loading: false,
        options: {
          page: 1,
          itemsPerPage: 40,
        },
        headers: [
      { text: 'Name', value: 'fullName' },
      { text: 'Med', value: 'med' },
      { text: 'Start Date', value: 'startDate' },
      { text: 'Create  ', value: '' },
    ],
    }
},
```

Here I have a field in header `Create` in that field I want to show a list of `drop-down` say for now `['A', 'B', 'C']` and on clicking on any options among the list I wanted to route to certain routes. How do I do it ?

Comment: does this link  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54129956/7714663 answer your question?

Comment: @this.girish I am using vuetify, can I combine v-data-table of vuetify with element? Since they both are different i don't think so

Comment: sorry, i'm not Vue expert, i was just trying to help you, someone else will answer this shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Expandable row: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#expandable-rows ?

Answer (score 2):

Vuetify **v-data-table** [provides a slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#slots) for each of the values.  I updated your example by giving the last column the name *path* so that it may be used in the item slot.

I added the **v-select** so that you get the drop down effect.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/BigtoyJ/pen/OJVdLvN?editors=1111)

```
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="res"
      item-key="Name"
      class="elevation-23"
    >
      <template v-slot:item.path="{ item }">
        <v-select
          v-model="cSel"
          :items="item.path"
      ></v-select>
      </template>    
    </v-data-table>


   data () {
    return {
      expanded: [],
      singleExpand: false,
      cSel: 'A',
      res: [
        {
          fullName: 'name 1',
          med: 'med 1',
          startDate: 'start  date 1',
          path:  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        },
       ],
       totalRes: 0,
        search: '',
        loading: false,
        options: {
          page: 1,
          itemsPerPage: 40,
        },
        headers: [
      { text: 'Name', value: 'fullName' },
      { text: 'Med', value: 'med' },
      { text: 'Start Date', value: 'startDate' },
      { text: 'Create  ', value: 'path', width: '200' },
     ],      
   }
```

For what you are trying to do the expanded row would work to place the links, but if you wanted to have custom data display (the data is in rows, or are other conversions needed) then you may want to consider the named slot.

Regards!
  ;-J